# Remove part of string from a list of strings where the part in itself is in the list of strings

Tags: r, regex

My list of strings is:

```
lst <- c("Consolidated Statements Of Operations", 
         "Consolidated", 
         "Linkedin Corporate Solutions Customers", 
         "Linkedin Corporate Solutions")
```

From the above list I want to remove `"Consolidated"` and `"Linkedin Corporate Solutions"` because they are part of other strings in the list.

Can anyone suggest how to do this in R using regex or any libraries, please?

Comment: `lst[!lst %in% c("Consolidated","Linkedin Corporate Solutions")]`?

Comment: Jaap :- but how do i get c("Consolidated","Linkedin Corporate Solutions")

Comment: I think you've already got a good answer that below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this...

```
lst[sapply(lst, function(x) sum(grepl(x, lst))==1)]

[1] "Consolidated Statements Of Operations"  "Linkedin Corporate Solutions Customers"
```

It works through `lst`, counts the number of strings containing that string, and only keeps the ones with just one (i.e. those containing only themselves)